# Why does my X-axis ticks make a little "jump" on safari with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have this graph on a website which works perfectly fine on chrome, but on safari or IE, when I do any of the following:

-change dataset

-change the dropdown below the blue button

-remove or add ticks in the "select population" button

the ticks on the X-axis with sometimes make little "jump" or a "hop" before going to their new position. This never happens on chrome. Why is this?

Here is a link to the website: http://servers.binf.ku.dk/hemaexplorerbeta/

This is the code that makes is bump:

```
SVG.select(".x.axis").transition().duration(1500)
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + AXIS_ROTATION + ")" 
        });
```

If I remove the transition().duration() it doesn't do it anymore, but then it doesn't change my x-axis fluently either.